# Lightshowpi throwing error on browser : Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have successfully install Lightshow pi on Raspberry pi 3 and through ssh using below command I can run the music successfully :

```
sudo python /home/pi/lightshowpi/py/synchronized_lights.py -file=/home/pi/lightshowpi/music/sample/closer.mp3
```

But I want the music should start from browser for that I have used php to execute the SSH command like below :

```
exec("sudo python /home/pi/lightshowpi/py/synchronized_lights.py --file=/home/pi/lightshowpi/music/sample/closer.mp3");
```

I am getting below error :

```
Need to setup SYNCHRONIZED_LIGHTS_HOME environment variable, see readme.
```

What I have missed during installation or any changes I have to make in the code to run it from browser?

Comment: Have you tried setting up the SYNCHRONIZED_LIGHTS_HOME? There might be something in the readme about it.

Comment: @kindall I don't know where to put SYNCHRONIZED_LIGHTS_HOME, I am new to this things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to start the music using below code :

```
<?php

$x = "sudo python ";
$y = "/home/pi/lightshowpi_new/py/synchronized_lights.py --file=";
$z = $x.$lightshowpihome.$y.'/home/pi/lightshowpi_new/music/sample/closer.mp3';

putenv("SYNCHRONIZED_LIGHTS_HOME=/home/pi/lightshowpi_new");

echo $z;
exec($z);
?>
```

[**putenv**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php) was the function to set the environment variable in PHP for lightshowpi